# Right click to tweet image (not link)

Tags: images, firefox, twitter

I'm looking for an addon for Firefox that adding an option in the right click menu that helps you to tweet an image. The tweet should contain the image, not the link to it.

[image: Two images side-by-side {Left} Example image within a webpage {Right} Image in a tweet]

Answer (score 1):

Some more searching revealed that there now exist something called
[Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards), and that some of the sites approved for images also provides addons for FireFox.

Started FireFox again, and searched for twitpic, and a few links down I found:

- [TwitrPix Express for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/twitrpix-express-for-firefox/)

  > Instantly share any photo from any web site on Twitter by right-clicking on the photo and clicking "Share photo on Twitter using TwitrPix" -- while you surf and without having to leave the site you are on.
  >   ...
  >   TwitrPix is a leading photo sharing site for Twitter users. Using TwitrPix Express for Firefox, you can upload and share any photo from any web site on Twitter without leaving the site you are on.
  >
  > **Simply right-click on the image you want to share and select "Share using TwitrPix."** Enter your Twitter information and click Share. A link to the image and your tweet (status message) will be posted on Twitter. A "view image" button will appear if you want to see the photo you just tweeted.
  >
  > The best part is that you don't need to visit Twitter, don't have to visit TwitrPix and as long as you have a Twitter account, there's nothing else you need to do. **A link to your photo and status update will appear on Twitter immediately.**
  >
  > - No TwitrPix account needed – you just need to have a Twitter account
  > - **Upload any photo from any web page without leaving the site you're on**

Maybe this or some of the other addons available when searching for *twitpic* or *twitter cards* or similar, will give you the wanted functionality!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search revealed the article ["Tweet Context for Firefox lets you tweet any link or image from the right click menu"](http://geekiest.net/post/Tweet-Context-for-Firefox-lets-you-tweet-any-link-or-image-from-the-right-click-menu.aspx), which talks about the [Tweet Context](//addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tweet-context/) add on.

From the article:

> To Tweet a page’s link, right click anywhere and select “Tweet this page”, the addon will automatically copy the page’s title and the link to your tweet. All you have to do is sign and tweet it. If you are already signed in, just click tweet. *You can also tweet an image in the same way.*

In other words, right clicking on an image gives you the option to tweet the image directly.

**Edit:**
 Installed FireFox to try it out, as a comment says that it doesn't work. And it seemed like it didn't, but then it struck me: *How does twitter handle images at all?*

So I searched and found: [How do I add an image to a tweet or how does twitter decide which image urls to render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061906). According to this page, a tweet can not hold an image, but if it holds a link to an image at a given set of web sites, then it will display the image.

In other words, the addon does most probably work, but only if the image is at the correct site. If not, you'll have to upload the image to any of the given sites before tweeting it, so that it can be embedded media.

See also the following articles:

- [Posting photos on Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20156423)
- [Now Playing on #newTwitter: Embedded Music, TV Shows, Slides and More](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/now-playing-newtwitter-embedded-music-tv-shows-slides-and-more)

Comment: it doesn't work as I expected. Only tweet link